I put new log configuration in logging laravel but it is still logging in the previous logging configuration
I am using Laravel 9 and the previous logging configuration was using loggly and now I changed it to AWS (cloudwatch) logging but not all logs are logged in AWS and it is still logging in the previous logging configuration (loggly). I have no idea why this is happening, I have tried to clear cache files. It is working in another server environment. Below is my logging configuration. Any help is appreciated.
    'default' => env('LOG_CHANNEL', 'cloudwatch'),
.....
    'channels' => [
    ....

        'daily' => [
            'driver' => 'daily',
            'path' => storage_path('logs/laravel.log'),
            'level' => env('ERROR_LEVEL', 'error'),
            'days' => 14,
        ],
....
        'loggly' => [
            'driver' => 'monolog',
            'level' => 'debug',
            'handler' => LogglyHandler::class,
            'formatter' => 'default',
            'with' => [
                'token' => env('LOGGLY_TOKEN'),
                'tag'   => '',
            ],
        ],

        'cloudwatch' => [
            'driver' => 'custom',
            'via' => \App\Logging\CloudWatchLoggerFactory::class,
            'sdk' => [
                'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION', ''),
                'version' => 'latest',
                'credentials' => CredentialProvider::memoize(CredentialProvider::instanceProfile())
            ],
            'retention' => 7,
            'level' => 'debug',
            'group_name' => env('CLOUDWATCH_GROUP', ''),
            'stream_name' => env('CLOUDWATCH_STREAM', ''),
        ],

